# android finger tip text entry

Tags: android, text, ocr

I wish to create an Android Note taking application

i want the user to be able to write words on the tablet screen just like writing on a notepad

i've been playing around with a number of examples and tutorials but cannot get distinct characters, each letter is automatically joined to the next.

i started with the marakana example "Android 2D Graphics Example" and went from there.

how do i allow the user to enter each letter without it being joined together?

once each word has been entered (and not "joined up") i would like to process the "rough" text and display the entered word with a "proper" typeface.